# SQL: Finding the closest Lat/Lon record on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

I have a data table on Google BigQuery with locations, call it TABLE_A.

This is how TABLE_A looks like:

```
ID,Lat,Lon
1,32.95,65.567
2,33.95,65.566
```

There's a second table with different items, call it TABLE_B. TABLE_B has the same schema as TABLE_A. This is a sample from TABLE_B:

```
ID,Lat,Lon
a,32.96,65.566
b,33.96,65.566
```

and I want to create a new table, TABLE_C, in which every row has items from TABLE_A and TABLE_B such that the items are the closest (i.e. the distance between the lat/lon pair is the minimal distance when joining the tables). This would be an example of TABLE_C with the above sample data:

```
ID_A,ID_B
1,a
2,b
```

My actual data is a table of properties with lat/lon pairs on one hand and   `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` on the other hand (I'm looking to find the closest weather station per property).

Comment: This is not a dup of that question - that one helps in calculating the distance between two points on the same table, it does nothing to find the minimum...

Comment: also check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678306/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<id_a INT64, id_b STRING>(a.id, b.id) ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(a.point, b.point) LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_a`) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_b`) b 
GROUP BY a.id
```

you can test, play with it using dummy data from your question as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_a` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 32.95 lat, 65.567 lon UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 33.95, 65.566
), `project.dataset.table_b` AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, 32.96 lat, 65.566 lon UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 33.96, 65.566
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<id_a INT64, id_b STRING>(a.id, b.id) ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(a.point, b.point) LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_a`) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_b`) b 
GROUP BY a.id
```

with result

```
Row id_a    id_b     
1   1       a    
2   2       b
```