# Alternative to using cross-join when dealing with two tables with millions of rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I am following the script below to find the closest lat-lon record on BigQuery.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<id_a INT64, id_b STRING>(a.id, b.id) ORDER BY 
ST_DISTANCE(a.point, b.point) LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_a`) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_b`) b 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Source
[SQL: Finding the closest Lat/Lon record on Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989172/sql-finding-the-closest-lat-lon-record-on-google-bigquery?rq=1)

My query won't complete however and I would reach the 6 hour mark in BQ. This is likely due to the size of the tables that I am working with.

```
table_a has 27M rows
table_b has 120M rows
```

Would you have suggestions on how I can modify the script above to make it work on the size of my tables?

Appreciate any insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below alternative

```
SELECT a_id, b_id FROM (
  SELECT a.id a_id, b.id b_id, ST_DISTANCE(a.point, b.point) distance
  FROM (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_a`) a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_b`) b 
)
WHERE true
QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a_id ORDER BY distance)
```

Comment: This gives me the "Resource exceeded during query execution" error.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative

```
SELECT a_id, APPROX_TOP_SUM(b_id, 1 / distance, 1)[OFFSET(0)].value as b_id
FROM (
  SELECT a.id a_id, b.id b_id, ST_DISTANCE(a.point, b.point) distance
  FROM (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_a`) a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point FROM `project.dataset.table_b`) b 
)
GROUP BY a_id
```

This approach uses [APPROX_TOP_SUM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_top_sum).
Note: Approximate aggregate functions are scalable in terms of memory usage and time, but produce approximate results instead of exact results.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: I tried this and I am not reaching the 6 hour mark anymore, however BigQuery is giving me the "Query exceed resource limits". My data in table b has 12 distinct states, so I can probably split the 120M row to about 10M rows each and run the query 12 times and just combine in the end. Is there a more efficient way than this? Thanks